# Shift Delete not working in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nemo

I don't know if this is just me or if this is a case of corrupt install but apparently shift+delete does not delete files permanently from anywhere on my system. It only moves files to the Trash which I don't want as the default behavior. I've followed a couple of different guides which were available online but nothing seems to be working.
I can't do a reinstall since this is my work system and I don't have any place to save my backup data as it's not allowed as per company policy.
Does anybody have any solutions for this?
Assistance is massively appreciated.

Comment: Go to Gnome **Settings -> Keyboard** and check that the Shift+Delete shortcut is ***not*** assigned to something else. Shift+Delete is hardcoded to *Files* (*Nautilus*) as you can check in *Files*, **Keyboard Shortcuts -> Editing** (third tab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Delete Files Permanently

When Files is open, go to the top of the screen and click **"Files"**, Then click **"Preferences"**, next click **"Behaviour"**.

Under the **"Trash"** heading, click the box in front of **"Show action to permanently delete files and folders"**

Now when you are using Files you can right click the object you want to delete and select **"Delete Permanently"** from the list. (You still have an option to **"Move to Trash"** when you prefer).

No need to `Shift Delete` to get rid of stuff forever but that should also work.